# Remove user and password at login in Debian 9 Stretch

Tags: user-interface, authentication, debian, beagleboneblack, lcd

I work on a project using BeagleBone Black and an LCD cape.

For that, I download the current BBB IOT image from their website and installed LXDE for user interface.

I want to create an application that starts at boot on the LCD.

[Login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KhNKJ.jpg)

I need to remove the login step at the startup.
I think that LightDM is used as a desktop manager (maybe helps), but for now I only succeed to auto insert the username.

Thank you.

Comment: Sounds like a question for [unix.se].

Answer (score 0):

https://elinux.org/Beagleboard:BeagleBoneBlack_Debian#i_take_full_responsibility_for_knowing_my_beagle_is_now_insecure

This page on the BBB will ensure you have let go of the sign on password section on your image. This first one is for root.

```
 - root_password=$(cat /etc/shadow | grep root | awk -F ':' '{print $2}')
 - sed -i -e 's:'$root_password'::g' /etc/shadow
```

This one is for no password. It has been a while since I tried these but I will make sure and reply.

```
 - echo "debian  ALL=NOPASSWD: ALL" >>/etc/sudoers
```